# 'AWSURLRequestRetryHandler.h' file not found

Tags: xcode, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, xcode8

I updated to Xcode 8 and also updated AWS though cocoapods to 2.4.8 and received the error 'AWSURLRequestRetryHandler.h' file not found' as well as something along the lines of AWSS3 module not found. It took me two days till someone else posted this exact same question but they deleted it. So I'm posting this again to help anyone else using AWS and migrating to Swift 3.

Answer (score 1):

Reverting back to 2.4.7 solved the problem, https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/issues/460